# function Window.focus doesn't work in IE (8, 9, 10, 11)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here is my code, and this code to open new tab and focus on it.

- If tab is not opened yet, I will open it with specify name.
- If tab is opened, I will focus on it by using window.focus();

Quick test: http://jsfiddle.net/u2jd2oLw/1/

Javascript Code

```
var tabs = [];
$('#btnOpenTab').on('click', function(){
    openTab('http://google.com.vn', 'GG');
});


function openTab(url, tabNm) {
    try {
        if (tabs[tabNm]) {
            tabs[tabNm].focus();
        } else {
            var mTab = window.open(url, tabNm);
            tabs[tabNm] = mTab;
            tabs[tabNm].focus();
        }
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

HTML Code

```
<button id="btnOpenTab">Open Tab</button>
```

Actually, I check in IE11, it occurred that "**Access is denied**"

And I tried to turn off option: "Turn on Pop-up Blocker" by un-check CheckBox.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a security feature in Windows:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979954

Here are a couple of work arounds to try:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/a250c431-9f09-441c-9b78-af067233ed78

[Giving a child window focus in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751912/giving-a-child-window-focus-in-ie8)

Comment: @JackDuong I don't have a Windows machine, so I can't be much of help but the only sane answer i come across is that to `focus()` work it should be called from the target window itself, in that case you need to some how inject your new tab with a script which calls `window.focus()`

Answer (score 0):

This will work once due to the security issues

```
$(function() {
  $('#btnOpenTab').on('click', function(){
    openTab('http://google.com.vn', 'GG');
  });
});

function openTab(url, tabNm) {
  var mTab = window.open("", tabNm);
  mTab.document.write('<body onload="window.focus(); location.replace(\''+url+'\')">Please wait...</body>');
  mTab.document.close();
}
```

It failed to run twice because once the page loads it is no longer same origin.

I tried with an iFrame, but Google blocks that too now

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not what I want. :(

Comment: I know. So you are SOL.