# Internert Explorer window.open not focusing after first click

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser, frontend

In Internet Explorer, when I click the link for the second time, the window already opened, but it is not focused. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox. 
With the following code:

```js
function open_page(url, name, features) {
  var win = open(url, (name == null ? 'page' : name), (features == null ? 'menubar=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,width=1024,height=768,resizable=1' : features));
  if (win == null) {
    alert('Can not open');
  } else {
    document.isUnloading = false;
    win.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="image" id="pdf" name="pdf" style="padding: 2px; background-color: white; border: 1px dotted white;" title="PDF" src="/images/buttons/pdf.png" alt="PDF" onclick="open_page('http://www.w3schools.com'); return false;" onmouseover="document.getElementById('pdf').style.border='1px solid #a0a0ff'; document.getElementById('pdf').style.backgroundColor='#f0f0ff';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('pdf').style.border='1px dotted white'; document.getElementById('pdf').style.backgroundColor='white';">
```

Comment: You are not the only one asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898232/function-window-focus-doesnt-work-in-ie-8-9-10-11 - which I answered a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1** This SHOULD work on same origin but may not

```
var win;
function open_page(url, name, features) {
  name = name  || 'page';
  if (win && !win.closed) window.open(url,name).focus();
  else {
    win = open(url,name, (features == null ? 'menubar,toolbar,scrollbars,width=1024,height=768,resizable' : features));
    if (win == null) {
alert('Can not open.');
    } else {
      document.isUnloading = false;
      win.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

**Example 2**

This is a better bet, add

```
<script>window.onload=function() { window.focus() }</script>
```

to the pages you open assuming there is no other onload, if there is one already, add `window.focus()` to that instead

If the page you want to open is a PDF, then use

```
<script>window.onload=function() { window.focus() }</script>
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="yourpdfpage.pdf"></iframe>
```

Comment: I am not sure where to add window.onload

Comment: But the first page in opening in new tab and on second click it opens in same tap. Ultimately it is 2 pages opened

Comment: I am not sure what you are telling me. I thought your problem was that if the tab or popup is open, it will not focus on the second click to open a page  - Here are two solutions to the same issue

Comment: It seems to be opening new tabs everytime I click afetr doing this which I will not have ...if (win && !win.closed) window.open(url,name).focus();
  else {
    win = open(url, (name == null ? 'page' : name), (features == null ? 'menubar=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,width=1024,height=768,resizable=1' : features));

Comment: You removed name and use test. I am trying to see what is needed

Comment: If I add name, I get access denied because the fiddle does not live in the the same origin as the page that popups. Have a look at my code and copy it so the page name stays the same

Comment: I would go with my second example.

Comment: My second example is to NOT have parent focus but to add this this the page you popup: `<script>window.onload=function() { window.focus() }</script>` - if that is a PDF, then wrap the PDF in an iFrame

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132899/discussion-between-jenny-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I am back if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

On the pop-up page add:

```
<body onload="FocusWindow()">
```

Add this function to a JavaScript file that is referenced in the pop-up window.

```
function FocusWindow() {
window.focus();
}
```

Background Info on why this happens:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/979954

Basically you can't focus a window from a different window, you can only focus from the window you want to focus, yes, you read that right.

So my workaround utilizes this bug by having it focus itself onload.

Comment: When I had this issue I believe this was the only way I could get it to work at all. Inline function referring to JS in another file. This was after lots of attempts. Maybe yours works too but I know mine does.

Comment: The JS needs to be a separate file, I know it sounds stupid, but it's IE we are talking about here.